# Selenium Python - Stale Element Reference Exception

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some public information from a government site and need to scroll through the pages by clicking "Próximo", but I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lantri_rafael/codigo/diariosbr/raf/dom-saojoaquimdabarra/coleta_selenium3.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/lantri_rafael/codigo/diariosbr/raf/dom-saojoaquimdabarra/coleta_selenium3.py", line 36, in main
    pag = page()
  File "/home/lantri_rafael/codigo/diariosbr/raf/dom-saojoaquimdabarra/coleta_selenium3.py", line 19, in page
    pag.click()
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env_diariosbr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env_diariosbr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env_diariosbr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env_diariosbr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of [object String] "{\"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf\":\"d099f837-9079-4668-a534-3099fc73a76c\"}" is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Below the code and site

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

def page():
    pag = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Pagination"]/a[@class="next"]')))
    list_ed = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="jornal"]/li[@class="lista"]')
    def info():
        for ed in list_ed:
            el_text = ed.text 
            el = ed.find_element_by_xpath('a').get_attribute('href')
            print(el_text)
            print(el)
    info()
    pag.click()
    sleep(35)
    info()
    
    
        
    
 

def main():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.imprensaoficialmunicipal.com.br/sao_joaquim_da_barra")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    pag = page()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is your line of code `pag.click()` in your `page()` function within the for loop?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: sometimes code may run too fast and JavaScript has no time to update HTML in browser after your click and before you get `pag = WebDriverWait(...)` and it may get old element before it updates HTML - usually it need short `sleep()` after `click()` (and I don't mean `element_to_be_clickable` because it may find old element which also was clickable)

Comment: Hi @furas ! I put the full traceback and tried to put a sleep (35), but the error continues. I still have figured out how to solve this

Comment: your problem is that after `click()` you have to use again  `find_elements_by_xpath` to get new values from new HTML on page. It will not update `list_ed` automatically. At this moment after `click` you use old list `list_ed` which has references to elements in old HTML - but now browser has new HTML and old list has references to wrong elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because `click()` loads new `HTML` in browser and you have to use again `find_elements_by_xpath` to get elements in new HTML. But you use all time the same list with references to elements on first page and it can't find these elements on next pages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

def info(driver, delay=5):
    next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Pagination"]/a[@class="next"]')))

    all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="jornal"]/li[@class="lista"]')
    
    for item in all_elements:
        text = item.text 
        href = item.find_element_by_xpath('a').get_attribute('href')
        print(text)
        print('href:', href)
        print('---')
    
    next_page.click()
    sleep(delay)

def page(driver):
    for _ in range(5):
        #info(driver)
        info(driver, 2)

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.imprensaoficialmunicipal.com.br/sao_joaquim_da_barra")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    pag = page(driver)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot! @furas